# MS Word - Create Style with Pre-made text

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

So I am making a ms word template and was creating a custom style that would have a pre-determined text. Example is, after clicking the custom style, it would generate an auto text: 
`Fig.1. Insert text here` 
Would that be possible?

Best regards.

Comment: I think this would be better off on super user.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Static text cannot be part of a Word style. If you're numbering something, then you can include static text as part of the numbering definition, for example Figure + number. Link the numbering definition to a style and you'll get that text when applying the style. But everytime you apply the style the number will increment.

Otherwise, use BuildingBlocks/AutoText, formatted with the style, and insert that - which will automatically apply the style.